# Mypy complains about incompatible type when variable type is subset of expected type

Tags: python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

Trying to build an [`xarray`](http://xarray.pydata.org) `Dataset`, where we build the input to the arguments "coords" and "attrs" before passing it to the constructor:

```py
coordinates = {"time": ("time", time_coordinates)}
attributes = {"some_flag": False}
...
ds = xr.Dataset(data_vars=variables, coords=coordinates, attrs=attributes)
```

What puzzles me is the output of `mypy` run against this code:

```
error: Argument "coords" to "Dataset" has incompatible type "Dict[str, Tuple[str, Any]]"; expected "Optional[Mapping[Hashable, Any]]"
error: Argument "attrs" to "Dataset" has incompatible type "Dict[str, bool]"; expected "Optional[Mapping[Hashable, Any]]"
```

Isn't a `dict` a `Mapping`? And isn't `str` also `Hashable`? And aren't `Tuple`s and `bool`s of type `Any`, in any case? What do I not understand about mypy and/or Python type hints here?

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8293)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I looked in the wrong spot - the issue here is (as I learned from your comment) that `str` is not considered `Hashable`.. or generally speaking, the keys in `Mapping`s are not covariant, see also [this closed PR](https://github.com/python/typing/pull/273)

Comment: My understanding is that `str` **is** a `Hashable`, but since `dict` is a mutable data type you must be passing the exact same type for the keys, not a subtype. There is a possibility that the called function might add another `Hashable` key to the passed argument, breaking the source.

Comment: yes, thanks for clarifying this, I did not express this properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the information from [Selcuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2011147/selcuk), I found this somewhat verbose solution, as detailed in the [mypy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#invariance-vs-covariance): As the keys of `Mapping`s are invariant, one needs to hint explicitly that the `str` there is of type `Hashable`. (While strings are a subtype of `Hashable`, `Mapping`s keys are not covariant, disallowing subtypes.). Or, as [Selcuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2011147/selcuk) puts it in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67207604/mypy-complains-about-incompatible-type-when-variable-type-is-subset-of-expected#comment118795589_67207604):

> `str` **is** a `Hashable`, but since `dict` is a mutable data type you must be passing the exact same type for the keys, not a subtype. There is a possibility that the called function might add another `Hashable` key to the passed argument, breaking the source.

```py
coordinates: Dict[Hashable, Tuple[str, Any]] = {
    "time": ("time", time_coordinates)
}
attributes: Dict[Hashable, Any] = {"some_flag": False}
```